# hbase client API get stuck at table.get(row),

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, hadoop2

I am writing a Hbase Java Client using hbase's native API's.

I could connect to hbase and run various queries using the Hbase Client that i created. I ran my hbase client with "hbase classpath" command. Which resolves all the dependencies.

Now we want this hbase client to be part of project which has it as one of its component.
So after integrating it we need to run it as a part of War file of the project, (We need to run it as a part of rest API).
I have added hbase-site.xml. hdfs-site.xml and core-site.xml as resource and set as Resource to configuration object.

```
Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()

URL hbaseUrl=HbaseManagerServiceImpl.class.getClassLoader().getResource("hbase-site.xml");
conf.addResource(hbaseUrl.toString());
URL hdfsUrl=HbaseManagerServiceImpl.class.getClassLoader().getResource("hdfs-site.xml");
conf.addResource(hdfsUrl.toString());
URL coreUrl=HbaseManagerServiceImpl.class.getClassLoader().getResource("core-site.xml");
conf.addResource(coreUrl.toString());
```

when i tried to add only core-site.xml i got error saying "include failed" which file was present on that host, so added that file too in resource older which resolved my issue.

```
HTable table = new HTable(conf , "tableName");
```

I could successfully do scan and get row operations and fetch result.

```
Scan scanTable = new Scan();
Get row = new Get(key);
```

But when I am trying to do “ Result rowData = table.get(row); “

My code gets stuck and don’t show any error.

I am able to run same code with ""hbase classpath" command.
Do i need to set $HADOOP_CLASSPATH and $HBASE_CLASSPATH variables too, I am running my code through jetty webserver.

Below is the error trace:

```
java.io.InterruptedIOException: Giving up trying to location region in meta: thread is interrupted.
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:1391)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:1169)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:1123)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getRegionLocation(HConnectionManager.java:964)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RegionServerCallable.prepare(RegionServerCallable.java:72)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:113)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.get(HTable.java:780)
at com.connectApi.hbase_api.hbaseHelper.readTableData(hbaseHelper.java:148)
at com.yahoo.oe.core.services.impl.HbaseManagerServiceImpl.test(HbaseManagerServiceImpl.java:169)
at com.yahoo.oe.ws.impl.OEEndPointImpl.testHBase(OEEndPointImpl.java:175)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:322)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:131)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:184)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:155)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at yjava.servlet.filter.YHdrsFilter.doFilter(YHdrsFilter.java:73)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at yjava.cookie.CookieDataFilter.doFilter(CookieDataFilter.java:133)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at yjava.servlet.filter.DoNotTrackFilter.doFilter(DoNotTrackFilter.java:114)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at yjava.remote.ip.RemoteIPFilter.doFilter(RemoteIPFilter.java:98)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at yjava.security.yiv.servlet.InputValidationFilter.doFilter(InputValidationFilter.java:234)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.UserAgentFilter.doFilter(UserAgentFilter.java:83)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:365)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:159)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception !!!!java.io.InterruptedIOException: Giving up trying to location region in meta: thread is interrupted.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.commons.daemon.support.DaemonLoader.stop(DaemonLoader.java:200)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.FutureCallback.get(FutureCallback.java:128)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.FutureCallback.get(FutureCallback.java:30)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStop(Server.java:426)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:89)
at yjava.servlet.container.jetty.JettyDaemon.stop(JettyDaemon.java:47)
... 5 more
```

Comment: can you give hbase/hadoop version?

Comment: @Priyanka : kerberos enabled for Hbase?

Comment: Can you please check  these steps 1)hbase zkCli -server sandbox:2181
Once you connect, you can run, in the zkcli prompt:

2 ) ls /
Please paste the output of the above command.                                The baseZnode of "/hbase-unsecure " does not seem to exist. In general the base znode is "/hbase"

Comment: @Whitefret - Hadoop Version is Hadoop 2.6.0.20.1507121549 and Hbase version is 0.98.7.16.1602181953_h2

Comment: @RamPrasadG - Yes Kerberos is enabled and i could run my code with "hbase classpath" command, also i am able to do "hbase shell" successfully. Do i need to set kerberos properties separately in my code ?

I did executed all the steps Result - [storm, zookeeper, hbase]

Answer (score 2):

I am able to resolve this issue now. hbase-site.xml and other *-site.xml were not properly injected in java code, so i had to make below changes.

```
URL hbaseSite=HbaseManagerServiceImpl.class.getClassLoader().getResource("hbase-site.xml");


InputStream inputHbase = new URL(hbaseSite.toString()).openStream();

conf.addResource(inputHbase);
```

I checked if proper xml file is input i tried to print the input files content.

```
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

### At first, You check clientPort in hbase-site.xml file:

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
  <value>2222</value>
</property>
```

---

### And in java program: You must set clientPort the same as in hbase-site.xml file:

```
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2222");
```

---